# How would I setup routing and partial loading for a rails application with a central dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I am having trouble figuring out how to make my rails app work with a central dashboard. Basically I want it to work so that when a user clicks on a course from the list, the details of the course are loaded into the dashboard. The ajax part isn't too complicated, I am however struggling slightly with loading the partial in when ajax isn't being used. I figure I can simply put some logic in the view so that if @course != null it will load the partial.

The routes are also giving me a bit of difficulty. So I wanted the url to resemble the following: dashboard/student/:id/university/:id/course/:id

I came up with the following, but is there a better way?
http://pastebin.com/keEmaznw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your question. You've given us scant detail, and insufficient code. That said, regarding loading a partial with a nil object:

If you pass an object to a partial, Rails will take care of the rendering for you automatically, and no nil (instead of null, in Ruby talk) check is necessary:

```
= render @object
```

Regarding routes, yes, there is a better way: You should generally avoid nesting your routes more than two levels. This becomes a nightmare to test, and you end up writing very long method names:

```
edit_dashboard_student_university_course_path(@university, @course, @student)
```

You really don't want to be writing that in your view or your tests. think about it, if you want to edit a student, is it necessary to load the university and the course as well?

Comment: Im sorry, I should have been more detailed. So the way its structured when you login you are led to the dashboard which pulls the courses you are currently enrolled in on the left hand side. Universities have many courses, and a student has many courses through enrollment. When a student clicks on a course, I want to load its details. So the course belongs to a particular university. I though nesting its route would be a good idea for that reason, however I see what you mean. How would you suggest I structure the routes then? I would like the url to be at least /dashboard/student/id/course/id

Comment: That's much better. Remember you can use the `shallow` option too. That gives you `courses/id/students` but `students/id/edit` without having to load the course. Just another thing to think about.

Comment: I think I have a different idea. Basically I want the site to be a one page layout, with a dashboard page and everything gets loaded in with ajax if its supported. The issue is if there is no ajax, it will obviously have to be multiple pages. The issue I am having with the routes originates from this. I can get rid of nesting student under dashboard and somehow detect whether ajax is supported. If it is, then just load in the bits and use ember.js to modify the url. If its not supported then simply do redirecting and such. But I am not sure how to tackle the ajax detection portion.

Comment: It's vary hard to figure out what you're trying to do without concrete examples, but good luck anyway.